# Convergence in quadratic mean and in mean

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\mathrm{X, (X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, Y, (Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}$ $\in$ $\mathcal{L^2}$ be random variables. Prove that

($\mathrm{X_n}$ converge to $\mathrm{X}$ in $\mathcal{L^2}$ and $\mathrm{Y_n}$ converge to $\mathrm{Y}$ in $\mathcal{L^2}$) $\Rightarrow$ $\mathrm{X_nY_n}$ converge to $\mathrm{XY}$ in $\mathcal{L^1}$.

My attempts: I think Jensen's inequality is needed here, with the function $\phi$($\mathcal{x}$)=$\vert$$\mathcal{x}$$\vert$, because the assumption is similar to a property stated here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_mean, but I am unable to clearly formulate a strategy to solve this problem

Comment: How far have you gotten so far on the problem?  The question will be greatly improved if/when you provide more information that you think is relevant wrt this problem-statement you posted, and what you've tried on your own before posting here, with a specific question about exactly has you stuck, etc.

Comment: I edited it with my thoughts so far

Comment: That helps a lot; I'll upvote, because you made an attempt to improve your question, which is helpful to users who might like to answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** By the triangle inequality,

$$|X_n Y_n-XY| \leq |X_n-X| \cdot |Y| + |Y_n-Y| \cdot |X_n|.$$

Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show that

$$\int |X_n Y_n-XY| \, d\mathbb{P} \leq \sqrt{\int |Y|^2 \, d\mathbb{P}} \sqrt{\int |X_n-X|^2 \, d\mathbb{P}} + \sqrt{\int |X_n|^2 \, d\mathbb{P}} \sqrt{\int |Y_n-Y|^2 \, d\mathbb{P}}. \tag{1}$$

Prove that the $L^2$-convergence  $X_n \to X$ implies that

$$\sup_{n \geq 1} \int |X_n|^2 \, d\mathbb{P}< \infty.$$

Now conclude from $(1)$ that $X_n Y_n \to XY$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Isn't $sup_{n \ge 1} \int |X_n|^2 dP < \infty$ clear from $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in L ^2$?

Comment: @Diamir No, one could have $E(X_n^2)=n$ for every $n$.